# Tracking Apps Spyware

Tags: phone, spyware

Looking on how to best advise someone who continues to have phone hacking issues. She changes devices, carriers nothing stops it. Local law enforcement have been no help. Very detailed personnel information is getting out. What should She do? Someone is stalking her she is afraid but also lives a very normal life. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: This isn't enough detail. What information of yours is leaking, and why do you think it's coming from the phone? It is highly unlikely that someone can hack every one of your devices. The best thing to do is to talk to law enforcement or take the phone to someone who can inspect it to get more information about what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. I have only been using my phone and tablet. I believe it to be linked to my Gmail account. I had the account for years.I  can't access it anymore and have lost basically everything. Years of information and family photos etc.

Comment: I have had my information from my MyChart which is years of medical information, bank information pulled up and cash app. No money has been stolen. I do know someone uses a common variation of my first name but thats not my legal name. They have found medical information about my grown children. It is someone close to me because they no where to look, but can't find certain things on line.

Comment: I have honestly thought about going higher than local law enforcement because it is not just social media BS its very private information. I don't like my children and family involved, not knowing concrete information about who is responsible makes me very uncomfortable. I live a boring life. I did just settle a lawsuit but again it was against a large cooperation that has insurance and deals with things of this nature. Was not out of the ordinary.

Comment: So, it's not your phone but your Gmail account? How do you know what they found?

Comment: Someone has gone on social media sites and put copies of the information some of which is 12 plus years old as well as private pictures that were in the family but not put on Facebook etc. I never used sites like those till a couple of years ago and I never put things about my children as they were minors. Also my father was convicted of a major federal crime we had no contact for years but we were advised against public social media accounts by the FBI I am a very private person. I replaced phones within the last year changed carriers and it happens consistently.

Comment: Ok, then you have no idea how this info was obtained. You've jumped to "trackers" and "spyware" and "phones" and even "hacking". So, we can't help. We're more in the dark than you are. You need to work with a professional to check *everything* to work out what's going on.